# Advanced Installer add another directory into PATH variable (Windows)

Tags: java, variables, path, launch, advanced-installer

EDIT: Clarify the questions & my current situations.

Here is the current installer i made using Advanced Installer .

[image]

The result is, once installer run. I opened my computer, and check out the destination path it becomes:

**A. stored in**

```
C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\MyApp1
```

**B. stored in**

```
unknown??
```

**C. stored in**

```
C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\MyApp3
```

My question is, each of either **A or C** path that has been seen above. Can I **append it into the PATH System Variable** of the target machine as well using that Installer? How to achieve that using Advanced Installer?

*NB: Manual process of opening My Computer | Right Click | Properties | Advanced System Settings | etc... steps are not my preferred ways.*

The **PATH System Variable** i'm currently saying is this one :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add an environment variable using Advanced Installer. To achieve this you can go in the "Environment" page of the project and add a new variable as described in the following article:
http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/environment-variable-edit-dialog.html